# I don't understand how some parameters of Query Store in MS SQL Server works

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-query-store

According to official documentation: In sys.database_query_store_options we have options which can adjust Query Store workflow and performance.

From documentation:

"flush_interval_seconds - The period for regular flushing of Query Store data to disk in seconds. Default value is 900 (15 min)"

"interval_length_minutes - The statistics aggregation interval in minutes. Arbitrary values are not allowed. Use one of the following: 1, 5, 10, 15, 30, 60, and 1440 minutes. The default value is 60 minutes."

And now i have a problem:

1. If Query Store flush data to disk every 15min, why do i see query in QS tables in seconds after execution?
   As i understand QS tables are 'permanent' and they are stored in data base (on disk), so how does this parameter (flush_interval_seconds) work?
2. The same thing about interval_length_minute - when i saved QS output after 1 minute from last query execution and after 61 minutes i realised that they are more less the same, so what about this aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. flush_interval_seconds - The period for regular flushing of Query Store data to disk in seconds. That means flushing from memory to disk so that the information wouldn't be lost after server restart. Before the flushing you just read info from memory.
2. interval_length_minute - this is aggregation interval for query runtime statistics. The lower it is the finer granularity of the runtime statistics becomes.

None of the options sets a period after which the info will be available.

Comment: Thx, now i understand that thing like sys.query_store_query are just DMV and they are unavailable after server restart. How can i check and get the QS data stored on disk ?

Comment: No, they are available after server restart. You can lose up to 15 min but previous written data will be available.

Comment: there is still sth that i don't understand: To prove that i understand you well, that is what i did: run strange query  (being on local server), then restart my PC and check QS. I thought that this query wont be visible... and it IS...  and again, WHY?